# Slot Machine Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, animation

This is a fun little program I made of a fruit machine gambler, aka "slot machine". What mistakes am I making? How can I make this better OOP programming, less spaghetti?

```js
var spin = false;

var value1, value2, value3, value4;

var holdFirst, holdSecond, holdThird, holdForth = false;

var first, second, third, forth;

// ******************* constructor

function getValue() {
    var num = Math.random();

   if(num < 0.2) {
     this.card = '<i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>';
   }
   if(0.2 > num < 0.4 ) {
     this.card = '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>';
   }
   if(0.4 > num < 0.6){
     this.card = '<i class="fa fa-lemon-o"></i>';
   }
   if(0.6 > num < 1){
     this.card = '<i class="fa fa-car"></i>';
   }
}

// ***************** initial

function getInitial() {
 spin = true;

 function startSpining() {
  if(spin){
   value1 = new getValue();
   document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = value1.card;
   value2 = new getValue();
   document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = value2.card;
   value3 = new getValue();
   document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML = value3.card;
   value4 = new getValue();
   document.getElementById('value4').innerHTML = value4.card;
  }
 }

 setTimeout(function(){ 
  spin = false;
 }, 1000);

 setInterval(function(){ 
  startSpining();
 }, 10);
}
getInitial();

// ************** hold

function hold(el) {

 $(el).toggleClass('active');

 switch (el.name) {
  case 'first':
   holdFirst = !holdFirst;
   break;
  case 'second':
   holdSecond = !holdSecond;
   break;
  case 'third':
   holdThird = !holdThird;
   break;
  case 'forth':
   holdForth = !holdForth;
   break;
 }

}

// **************** Get new

function getNew() {

 var spin = true;




 function startSpining(firstCard, secondCard, thirdCard, forthCard) {
  
  this.someMethod = function (x) {
   if(spin && !holdFirst){
    x = new getValue();
   }

    };

  if(spin && !holdFirst){
    value1 = new getValue();
    document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = value1.card;
  }
 }

 function startSpiningFirst() {
  if(spin && !holdFirst){
    value1 = new getValue();
    document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = value1.card;
  }
 }

 function startSpiningSecond() {
  if(spin && !holdSecond){
    value2 = new getValue();
    document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = value2.card;
  }
 }

 function startSpiningThird() {
  if(spin && !holdThird){
    value3 = new getValue();
    document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML = value3.card;
  }
 }

 function startSpiningForth() {
  if(spin && !holdForth){
    value4 = new getValue();
    document.getElementById('value4').innerHTML = value4.card;
  }
 }

 setTimeout(function(){ 
  spin = false;
  console.log(value1.card, value2.card, value3.card, value4.card);
 }, 1000);

 setInterval(function(){ 
  startSpiningFirst();
  startSpiningSecond();
  startSpiningThird();
  startSpiningForth();
 }, 10);

}
```

```css
ul>li {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.active {
  background: #ff5a5f !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1 id="first"></h1>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li> <h2><i id="value1" class="fa"></i></h2> </li>
            <li> <h2><i id="value2" class="fa"></i></h2> </li>
            <li> <h2><i id="value3" class="fa"></i></h2> </li>
            <li> <h2><i id="value4" class="fa"></i></h2> </li>
          </ul>
             
      <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="getNew()">Spin</button>
          
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <button type="button" name="first" onclick="hold(this)" class="btn btn-default">Hold First</button>
            <button type="button" name="second" onclick="hold(this)" class="btn btn-default">Hold Second</button>
            <button type="button" name="third" onclick="hold(this)" class="btn btn-default">Hold Third</button>
            <button type="button" name="forth" onclick="hold(this)" class="btn btn-default">Hold Forth</button>
          </div>


          <h1 id="demo"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- You have a bug/basic misunderstanding of JS syntax: You can't do chained comparisons in JavaScript, so none of the `if(x > num < z)` lines work the way you think they do.

  Instead what happens is that it's being interpreted as `(x > num) < z`, which is the same as `true < z` or `false < z`. It still does *something* due to type coercion, however. The left-hand boolean value is converted to zero or one, and *then* compared. So you're always comparing either `1 < z` or `0 < z`.

  But even if the syntax worked like you think, it's *still* wrong: `0.2 > num < 0.4` would mean that `num` should be smaller than *both* 0.2 and 0.4. Which is another way of saying `num < 0.2`. **Except** that because of the boolean-to-number coercion, you instead end up with *the exact opposite*: The equivalent of checking `num > 0.2`.

  Point is, the code is not doing what you think it's doing.
- Why `card`? This isn't a deck of cards. Something like `symbol` seems more appropriate.
- `new getValue()`. There's a lot of weird going on here:

  1. `getValue` doesn't sound like a constructor function; it sounds like it's supposed to return a value. So putting `new` in front of it seems odd.
  2. If it is a constructor function, the JavaScript convention would be to name it with PascalCase, not camelCase.
  3. Why *doesn't* it just return a value? It'd be a lot simpler.
- Why is `getNew` called `getNew`? Why not just `spin`? Ok, you already have a variable called `spin`, but that should probably be `spinning` instead, since that's what describes.
- Wat?

  ```
  function startSpining(firstCard, secondCard, thirdCard, forthCard) {

      this.someMethod = function (x) {
          if(spin && !holdFirst){
              x = new getValue();
          }

    };

      if(spin && !holdFirst){
              value1 = new getValue();
              document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = value1.card;
      }
  }
  ```

  First of all: "start *spining*". Spellcheck that (it's all over the place). Secondly: This whole chunk is never called as far as I can tell, and I have no idea what the declaration of `this.someMethod` is supposed to do, or what the function itself is supposed to do (it's supposedly called with an argument, `x` which you then set to something... and then it does nothing? But of course `someMethod` is never called anyway). And the indentation is all over the place.
- Each time you spin, *you create a new 10ms interval timer*. Click 8 times, and you've got 8 timers running simultaneously, just waiting for `spin == true`. Probably not what you intend.
- "Hold forth" should be "Hold *fourth*". Ironically, "hold forth" *is* an expression in English. It means "talking lengthily, assertively, or tediously about a subject" (like how I'm doing here!). But that has little to do with slot machines.
- Why are you loading two versions of jQuery? And why load bootstrap's JS scripts? You don't need them for anything here, as far as I can tell.
- Why, when you're loading jQuery, aren't you using it for more? As far as I can tell it's only used for one single line: `$(el).toggleClass('active');`. That's nuts. You're loading a huge library (twice even!) for something that could be handled with 2-3 lines of plain JS.
  Meanwhile you're *not* using jQuery where it'd be useful. For instance, you're setting event handlers in the HTML when jQuery has much more feature-rich event handling. Using `onclick` attributes is an outmoded technique, and has been for many, many years now. Heck, you're not even using jQuery to find elements, which is perhaps *the* most basic use of jQuery.

I don't mean to be harsh, but you should probably read up on JavaScript in general. There's a lot here that seems to be just written-until-it-kinda-worked, with little understanding of *why* it suddenly worked. It seems cobbled together from disparate snippets of code.

And there's little reason to make this object oriented. Or, rather, it *is* object oriented since you're using the DOM, and the DOM is the Document *Object* Model. But there's little reason to invent your own constructors.

I'd do something like this:

```js
// Get a random symbol class
function getRandomIconClass() {
  var rand = Math.random();
  
  if(rand < 0.25) return "fa fa-anchor";
  if(rand < 0.50) return "fa fa-heart";
  if(rand < 0.75) return "fa fa-car";
  return "fa fa-lemon-o";
}

// Listen for "hold"-button clicks
$(document).on("click", ".wheel button", function () {
  var button = $(this);
  button.toggleClass("active");
  button.parent().toggleClass("hold");
  button.blur(); // get rid of the focus
});

$(document).on("click", "#spin", function () {
  // get a plain array of symbol elements
  var symbols = $(".wheel").not(".hold").find("i").get(); 
  
  if(symbols.length === 0) {
    alert("All wheels are held; there's nothing to spin");
    return; // stop here
  }
  
  var button = $(this);
  
  // get rid of the focus, and disable the button
  button.prop("disabled", true).blur();
  
  // counter for the number of spins
  var spins = 0;
  
  // inner function to do the spinning
  function update() {
    for(var i = 0, l = symbols.length ; i < l ; i++) {
      symbols[i].className = getRandomIconClass();
    }
    
    if(++spins < 50) {
      // set a new, slightly longer interval for the next update. Makes it seem like the wheels are slowing down
      setTimeout(update, 10 + spins * 2);
    } else {
      // re-enable the button
      button.prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
  
  // Start spinning
  setTimeout(update, 1);
});

// set the wheels to random symbols when the page loads
$(function () {
  $(".wheel i").each(function () {
    this.className = getRandomIconClass(); // not using jQuery for this, since we don't need to
  });
});
```

```css
.wheel {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.wheel .fa {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="wheels">

  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>

  <!-- add more wheels if you want; just remember to update the width in the CSS -->

</div>

<p class="text-center">
  <button id="spin" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Spin</button>
</p>
```

Addendum: I feel it's worth pointing out that the above doesn't behave like a slot machine (nor does the original implementation). It's more like rolling dice, since each "wheel" can assume *any* value on each update.

A more "realistic" implementation would be to cycle through the possible values, in order, but make the number of cycles random.

```js
var SYMBOL_CLASSES = ["anchor", "heart", "car", "lemon-o"].map(function (klass) {
  return "fa fa-" + klass;
});

$(document).on("click", ".wheel button", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").blur().parent().toggleClass("hold");
});

$(document).on("click", "#spin", function () {
  var wheels = $(".wheel").not(".hold").find("i"),
      wheelCount = wheels.length;
  
  if(wheelCount === 0) {
    alert("All wheels are held; there's nothing to spin");
    return;
  }
  
  var button = $(this).prop("disabled", true).blur();
  
  // keep track of running wheels
  var counter = wheelCount;
  function stopped() {
    if(--counter === 0) {
      button.prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
  
  // create a bunch of wheel-spinning functions, each slightly offset
  var steps = wheels.each(function (i, element) {
    var wheel = $(this),
        count = 50 + (i * 3) + (Math.random() * 20 | 0),
        spins = $(this).data("current-symbol");
    
    function spinner() {
      element.className = SYMBOL_CLASSES[++spins % wheelCount];
      if(spins < count) {
        setTimeout(spinner, 1 + spins * 2);
      } else {
        wheel.data("current-symbol", spins % wheelCount);
        stopped();
      }
    };
    
    spinner();
  });
});

$(function () {
  $(".wheel i").each(function () {
    var rand = Math.random() * 4 | 0;
    $(this).data("current-symbol", rand).addClass(SYMBOL_CLASSES[rand]);
  });
});
```

```css
.wheel {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.wheel .fa {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="wheels">

  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wheel clearfix">
    <i></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hold</button>
  </div>

  <!-- add more wheels if you want; just remember to update the width in the CSS -->

</div>

<p class="text-center">
  <button id="spin" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Spin</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

Your indentation is all out of whack; in some places, you have unnecessary indenation, and in others you don't have necessary indentation.

For example, in the `getValue` function, why are those `if` statements indented?

And, in the `.someMethod` method of the `startSpinning` function of the `getNew` , the closing bracket should have another indent.

---

Your constructor should have a name describing what object it is returning, not what it is doing.

---

Your `getValue` class really isn't/shouldn't be a class.

All it is doing is returning a value; why isn't it just a normal function?

---

To make this thing "more object oriented", I recommend that you put all of this into a class.

Right now, you have variables spread out, and you have functions with names that make them sound like they are methods for a class (`get...`), even though they aren't.

You should make a classes like `SlotMachine` and `Spinner` where `SlotMachine` has a few `Spinner`s that have `spin` methods.

---

You should make your function names much, *much* more specific.

`someMethod` -- this tells me absolutely nothing.

`getNew` -- get new what? If you are getting a new object, this should be class, and then you should be getting a new whatever with the `new` keyword.

---

It should be spelled "fourth", not "forth".

---

I'm not sure if this is an issue on all browsers, but it has been an issue for me before on Google Chrome:

By using `setInterval` and `setTimeout`, you are creating multiple threads for code to run simultaneously.

However, when with more than one `setInterval` running, you are going to get some timing issues.

Issues for me in the past have been that some code is skipped, or the timing gets all messed up and nothing runs at the interval you want it to.

To fix this, I recommend that you try to keep everything on one thread; try finding a way to combine the functions being run in the `setInterval` in `getNew` with the functions being run in the `setInterval` in `getInitial`.

Again, this is only sometimes a problem on some browsers.

---

Now to talk about your HTML.

The tags inside the `head` tags should be indented. Some are, some aren't, and that is even worse than not having them indented at all.

You should try running your code through an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 7):

**Random Issues**

This seems bad:

```
function getValue() {
    var num = Math.random();

      if(num < 0.2) {
        this.card = '<i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>';
      }
      if(0.2 > num < 0.4 ) {
        this.card = '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>';
      }
      if(0.4 > num < 0.6){
        this.card = '<i class="fa fa-lemon-o"></i>';
      }
      if(0.6 > num < 1){
        this.card = '<i class="fa fa-car"></i>';
      }
}
```

When called repeatedly by this and similar:

```
value1 = new getValue();
```

I'm no Javascript expert, but I think you could improve performance by generating a large number of random slot machine sequences when the program starts, rather than calling `Math.random()` repeatedly as the program is running.  Maybe the performance gain is not that important, but I think it is worth mentioning.  Also, when you start thinking about generating a large number of sequences, you could think about ways to manipulate the results, potentially for gameplay reasons (such as a power-up increases the odds of a certain value).

This may not apply so much to Javascript, but definitely in other languages calling the equivalent of `Random()` can be costly.

I looked up `Math.random()` and it appears that there may be better options for better random generation.  See this Stack Overflow answer about [Javascript randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885196/1497671).

Comment: Why are you reviewing a mix of my answer's code, and OP's code?

Comment: Also, there's no `Random` object in JavaScript, just the `Math.random()` function, which is also what's used in the SO answer you linked to.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the mistake with reviewing your code!

Comment: Roger that. I'd go over the review again if I were you, though. As far as I can tell, OP's code is _not_ "good and clean and easy to understand". Don't mean to sound like a self-important ass, but I think you might have been looking more at my code for that as well. Also, I'm curious: What's "the new Javascript array syntax" you're referring to?

Comment: You are partially correct. Thanks for pointing it out, its worthwhile to try to improve the answers on the site.